# Wordpress is not able to change themes

Tags: themes, cache, homepage

Wordpress Website has two themes, newspaper magazine and twenty twenty, it uses by default newspaper magazine, if I change to twenty twenty, the homepage remains using newspaper magazine, but if I go to any other link or post, it uses twenty-twenty, also, the homepage remains the same no matter what changes I perform to it, even setting other pages to be the homepage.
Not sure if this is a cache issue

Things I've done so far :

wp-rocket was being used and it was removed 3 days ago
Cloudflare was used but was deactivated 3 days ago as well.
I have cleared all browsers cache several times
deactivated and activated all plugins
Reinstall WordPress and themes

Comment: That is almost always a caching issue.   You mentioned the browser cache and the litespeed cache, but there could be others.    Do you have any caching plugins like W3 Total Cache?    Do you use a CDN like Cloudflare?

Comment: wp-rocket and cloudflare were activated but removed 3 days ago. I have used other computer with other IP and the issue persists .

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved now,  it was caused by an .htaccess file placed in the uploads folder